# so + auxiliary + subject

Tags: inversion

> Lily had a wonderful time and received a fine gift, _________.

> A. so had Lucy B. so did Lucy  C. so Lucy did D. so it was with Lucy

The given answer is D, but I'm wondering if B is also possible.  I'd like to have your native opinions on this. Thank you.

Comment: What is the source of the question?

Comment: Are you sure about the punctuation? None of those is correct after a comma.

Comment: Yes, in the test, a comma was used.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a teacher or test writer has learned a phrase and wants to use it (rather than wanting to communicate and find a phrase to do so.)

There's no reason to use "so it was with Lucy".

You might use this phrase to mean "and the situation with Lucy was analogous". Here's an example from Wikipedia:

> The Ancient Hebrews, in referring to all who were not Hebrews as Gentiles, were indulging in ethnocentrism, not in racism. So it was with the Hellenes who denominated all non-Hellenes.

Notice first the formal, academic style of this quote, and the formation of an analogy between the Ancient Hebrews and the Hellenes.

This is quite different from the simple description of a good time and a fine gift.

The correct way to indicate that Lucy also had a good time and gift would be ", and so did Lucy".

The use of "fine" to describe the gift is also stilted and unnatural.